# How to associate bat files to x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, native, graalvm-native-image

For the link below

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2022\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022.lnk
```

the properties follows:

```
Target: %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
Open File Localtion: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

How to change double click behaviour of bat files from "cmd" to "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" to use graalvm features like native-image?

Comment: Not direct answer, but for one file you could do this:  the `vcvars64.bat` file basically sets environment variables for that shell.  You can call that batch file from your own.  Near the start of your batch file (before you want to use graalvm, etc), just add a line `call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`  - that should define all those environment variables, meaning those tools should be available to your batch file.

Comment: {call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"} in the first line returns {Files\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.}

Comment: {%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"} returns {[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'} which is good. But the next line of bat file is not triggering, for example {native-image -march=native --enable-preview --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector -jar target\com.tugalsan.gvm.license-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar}

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Make it `call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`  -- `%comspec% /k` starts a new shell and "keeps" it.  Whereas `call` runs the batch file you call then continues with this one.

Comment: I confirm it is working now, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @GregHNZ answered, below is an example bat file content to compile native, that can be called by doubleclick

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
native-image -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=config -march=compatibility --enable-url-protocols=http,https --enable-preview --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector -jar target\com.tugalsan.gvm.vnc.web-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.tugalsan.gvm.vnc.web
```